# Launching own bootloader

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm

How can I launch own bootloader novadays?
In all tutorials I've found on writing operating systems, they write about floppy disc, and suggest programs which doesn't match with x64 architecture.

Comment: What hardware?  What boot ROM?

Comment: What about http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/boot-loader.aspx? It has won several awards and it was written in the last two years. You will need to convert it from MASM to NASM but the core concepts are all there.

Comment: intel, simplest bootloader @ snmcdonald I'll try it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use kvm as a virtual machine.
http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page